# Set of custom objects contains the same object

Tags: java, set

I am seeing some weird behaviour of Java `Set`. Here is the very simple code snippet I'm having issues with:

```
public Set<StopSequence> reduce() {
    Set<StopSequence> stopSequences = new HashSet<StopSequence>();
    StopSequence currentSequence = null;

    for (StopTime stopTime: mStopTimes) {
        if (stopTime.getStopSequence() == 0) {
            //beginning of a new sequence
            if (currentSequence != null) {
                if (stopSequences.add(currentSequence)) {
                    System.out.println("Added sequence:");
                    System.out.println(currentSequence.toString());
                }   
                currentSequence.clear();
            } else {
                currentSequence = new StopSequence();
            }
            currentSequence.add(stopTime.getStopId());              
        } else {
            currentSequence.add(stopTime.getStopId());
        }
    }

    Iterator<StopSequence> iterator = stopSequences.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(iterator.next());
    }

    return stopSequences;
}
```

Now have a look at the console output and you will see the problem:

Output of the first `System.out.println`, everything seems fine:

```
Added sequence: com.bviproject.gtfsobjects.StopSequence@d48dbbe6
Added sequence: com.bviproject.gtfsobjects.StopSequence@d5e1c8a1
Added sequence: com.bviproject.gtfsobjects.StopSequence@c98eb21
Added sequence: com.bviproject.gtfsobjects.StopSequence@79baf504
Added sequence: com.bviproject.gtfsobjects.StopSequence@6617f5f6
Added sequence: com.bviproject.gtfsobjects.StopSequence@7d7554ff
```

Output of the second `System.out.println`, my `Set` only contains the same object. What is happening??

```
com.bviproject.gtfsobjects.StopSequence@dd017ba7
com.bviproject.gtfsobjects.StopSequence@dd017ba7
com.bviproject.gtfsobjects.StopSequence@dd017ba7
com.bviproject.gtfsobjects.StopSequence@dd017ba7
com.bviproject.gtfsobjects.StopSequence@dd017ba7
com.bviproject.gtfsobjects.StopSequence@dd017ba7
com.bviproject.gtfsobjects.StopSequence@dd017ba7
com.bviproject.gtfsobjects.StopSequence@dd017ba7
```

Comment: Are you certain that the code given here produces the output you gave? I ask because "Added sequence:" should be on its own line each time. Also, the code only creates *one* `StopSequence` object, so I don't see how it can even produce the first set of output. I suggest that you write a program, separate from your original code, which compiles and reproduces the exact problem which you are asking about. Make sure you restrict this new program to the code which is necessary in reproduce the issue at hand.

Comment: Yes I just trimmed the `\n` to save some space. I'll try to create a new StopSequence every time see if that work. But why do I get this output anyways?

Comment: Yep that worked, I'm still curious about why I got that output in the first place...

Comment: In your original code, calling `stopSequence.add()` simply adds the same object to the `List` over and over and over and over...

Comment: So why do I get different addesses in the "Added sequence" statement?

Comment: That is where I am confused. My guess is that the output you posted is *not* from this `reduce()` method. I say this because from the code above "Added sequence:" should be on a separate line from the object's hashcode. Is there another place in your program that produces similar output?